# Is f continuous at (0,0)?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, proof-writing

$$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}
                x \sin^2\left(x+y\right)/(y^4+\sin^2x), & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
                0, & (x,y)=(0,0) \\
            \end{cases}$$
Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

I used path test along the pathes: $y=0$, $x=0$, $y=x$, $y=(-x)$, $y=sinx$. Everywhere I had the answer $0$. But I have no idea how to proof that limit is zero according to definition. And in wolfram alpha it was said that limit does not exist. But I cannot find method of proving that limit does not exist.

Comment: I think the path $x=y^2$ does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=\sqrt{x}$ you have
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x \sin^2(x+\sqrt{x})}{x^2+\sin^2x}=\frac{1}{2}$$
So the limit doesn't exist.